# Delete from SQLite where Date column in List<DateTime>

Tags: c#, sqlite

Using C# I have `List<DateTime> dates`, I need to delete from my `Trip` table where `Trip.Date` is in my list of dates.

I was attempting to user `string.Join` to create a csv of dates and pass that as the parameter but it creates a literal and therefore doesn't work. So I'm stuck - should I create a temp table and loop through the dates adding them to the temp table? Is this even possible in SQLite?

My current (non-working) code:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _sqliteDatabasePath))
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("DELETE FROM Trip ");
    sb.Append("WHERE Date IN (?) ");

    conn.Execute(sb.ToString(),
        new object[] {
             dates
        });
}
```

Error from the above code:

> SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error

I also tried

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("DELETE FROM Trip ");
sb.Append("WHERE Date IN (SELECT * FROM ?) ");
```

same error as above.

I guess I could append a delete statement for each date but probably not best practice.

Comment: Please tell us what doesn't work? Any error or sth.?

Comment: @Sebi - I've just added it to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I decided to just build up the query using the appropriate number of `?` and the `List<DateTime> dates` as the parameters as below:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _sqliteDatabasePath))
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("DELETE FROM Trip ");
    sb.Append("WHERE Date IN ( ? ");

    if (dates.Count > 1)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < dates.Count; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(", ? ");
        }
    }

    sb.Append(")");

    conn.BeginTransaction();
    conn.Execute(
        sb.ToString(),
        dates.Cast<object>().ToArray());
    conn.Commit();
}
```

This worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SQLiteCommand` and add all the parameters manually.
One way to do it is like this:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), _sqliteDatabasePath))
{
    conn.Open();
    SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand("", conn);

    List<string> paramNames = new List<string>(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count; i++)
    {
        paramNames.Add("@date" + i.ToString());
        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date" + i.ToString(), dates[i]);
    }
    sqlCommand.CommandText =
        string.Format("DELETE FROM Trip WHERE Date IN ({0}) ", 
        string.Join(", ", paramNames));
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: I just get the error SQLiteCommand does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Comment: Did you install SQLite from Nuget Package Manager. I am using [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite). What options does your SQLiteCommand class have for a constructor?